# Excercise in "C Programming: A modern Approach"

Tags: c, math, modulo

if anyone could answer me why this works, it would be greatly appreciated. The exercise (chapter 4, ex 7 and 8) says that if you have the expression:
9 - ((total - 1) % 10)
then, you could be tempted to simplify it like this:
10 - (total % 10)
But this would not work. Instead he offers the alternative:
(10 - (total % 10)) % 10

Now, I understand how he got to the first simplification, but not why it's wrong, or why does the second one works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way is the 'alternative' a simplification!?  It has the same number of operands and operators as the original, and in most cases the `%` operator is more expensive than `-`.  I don't know the book, but if it were any good surely it is explained in the text?

Comment: It's an exercise. You have to tell why the first 'simplification' is wrong, and if the second one would work. The book just provides answers to some exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the outputs for `total = 10` to see that the second expression is not equivalent.

Note also that the third expression is *not* equivalent to the first expression unless `total > 0` (because the behaviour of `%` is implementation-defined in pre-C99 C, and defined but not what you want in C99).

Assuming that `total > 0`, the first and third expressions are equivalent due to the following mathematical identity:

```
(a % b) == (((a + c) % b) - c) % b
```

To understand why, imagine doing the operations on a clock-face.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. Could you show me the steps, applying the identity to the expressions?

Comment: @Facu: `a = (total-1)`, `b = 10`, `c = 1`.

Comment: Nice answer.  Though I wonder what the author thinks this exercise tests w.r.t. programming skills as opposed ot math skills?

Comment: `%` is not implementation-defined for negative numbers. It's well-defined, unfortunately in the mathematically-incorrect way. (The result takes its sign from the numerator instead of from the denominator.)

Comment: @R.: The behaviour of `%` is defined in terms of the behaviour of `/`, i.e. `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`.  In Pre-C99 C, it is implementation-defined whether `(a/b)` rounds toward zero or negative infinity for negative values of `a`.

Answer (score 4):

x %m has a range of (-m, m) in most C implementations. Mathematically it is generally defined from (0, m). Hence by adding m the modulo again will convert the C to the mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

This is because modulo in C allows for negative numbers.

so -5 % 10 is -5 instead of 5.

In the first case, the 9 - ((total - 1) % 10) is always positive.

In the second case it can be negative if -10 < total < 0. In the 3rd case it is again wrapped around for negatives back into the positive range.

It is a common thing for modulo because generally you want it for positives only(not sure why they implemented it for negatives).

Comment: @AbstractDissonance- are you sure about this?  I was under the impression that the C spec left the behavior of modulus with negative values unspecified.

Comment: Actually, the result is implementation-defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please explain the steps to go from 9 - ((total - 1) % 10) to (10 - (total % 10)) % 10? That's the thing I don't understand

Comment: @Facu T: You can't, because they *aren't* the same!

Comment: And if you assume that total is always positive? I'm sorry, but I've just started to program, and my math is rusty

Comment: @Facu T: The result for `total = 0` is implementation-defined for the first one.  If you assume that `total > 0`, then yes, they are the same.  This relies on the mathematical identity `(a % b) = (((a+c) % b) - c) % b`.

Comment: would you explain why the two are the same? (if total>0)

Comment: The result is **not** implementation-defined. `neg%pos` is, unfortunately, defined to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

To show why 9-((total)%10) is wrong, use a contradiction.

Let `total` = 10.

Then 9-((10-1)%10) ==> 9-(9%10) ==> 9-9 = 0.

But, 10-(10%10) ==> 10 -0 = 10.

Thus, 10-((total)%10) is not equivalent to 9-((total-1)%10)

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is not a simplification and neither expression is equvalent to the first so the premise is flawed from the start:

The following:

```
int total ;
for( total = -10; total <= 10; total++ )
{
    printf( "%d:\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", total,
                                 9 - ((total - 1) % 10), 
                                 10 - (total % 10), 
                                 (10 - (total % 10)) % 10 ) ;
}
```

Produces:

```
-10:    10      10      0
-9:     9       19      9
-8:     18      18      8
-7:     17      17      7
-6:     16      16      6
-5:     15      15      5
-4:     14      14      4
-3:     13      13      3
-2:     12      12      2
-1:     11      11      1
0:      10      10      0
1:      9       9       9
2:      8       8       8
3:      7       7       7
4:      6       6       6
5:      5       5       5
6:      4       4       4
7:      3       3       3
8:      2       2       2
9:      1       1       1
10:     0       10      0
```

The last is only equvalent for integers greater than zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to consider the context of the exercise. Total is greater than zero, always. I just dont understand why the first and third expressions are equivalent for total > 0

Comment: @Facu T:  Is it the purpose of the book to teach you programming or mathematics?

Comment: That's not a question for me. Anyway, nobody gave me the steps to go from 1 to 3. I understand that its because a mathematical identity, but I still don't know how to apply it to get to 3

Comment: @Facu T:  My point was that solving this problem tests your math ability not your programming ability.  Unless it is a required homework assignment, I'd move on.  So far this text has not impressed me much - especially its phenominal price! And the student guide is a separate purchase at the price of a good stand-alone text.